# ClickableSpan OnClick is not being called for multi spans

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

```
public class MyClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan {

    private String keyWord;
    Context context;

    public MyClickableSpan(String keyWord, Context context) {
        this.keyWord = keyWord;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("KeyWord",keyWord);
        context.startActivity(intent);

        // TODO do something
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setUnderlineText(true);
        ds.setColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

When I add more than one span to my SpannableString UpdateDrawState is working fine for all words and all target words become red and underlined, but OnClick is being called only for first word and other words aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using htmlTextView.getText() to create SpannableString and those words was links words in html text source so the click listener was not working 
when i changed it to

SpannableString spannableString = htmlTextView.getText().ToString();

it works but i lost html design for text.